# Facebook: open graph checkins in on one map

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, checkin

I have `Open Graph` feature in my app. I have to maintain the total `check-ins` in my Facebook account. And have to show the all checked-in places in one map. `Foursquare` app used this in their app. But i don't know, how to implement like that.

They have used two ways of showing in aggregation,
First one is,

[image]

And the second one is,

[image]

So, I have to do the both like Foursquare app. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely using the map custom aggregation feature.  Check out the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#styles.  You'll need to attach location data to your actions in order for this aggregation to work.  You can learn more about the Place property at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#places