# facebook open graph check-in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have Open Graph feature in my app. I have to maintain the total check-ins in my Facebook account. And have to show the all checked-in places in one map. Foursquare app used this in their app. But i don't know, how to implement like that.
They have used two ways of showing in aggregation, First one is, [Image1](http://demo.greatinnovus.com/parii/screenshot/Checkins.png) And the second one is, [Image2](http://demo.greatinnovus.com/parii/screenshot/FourSquare.png)
So, I have to do the both like Foursquare app. Please help me in this.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198626/facebook-open-graph-checkins-in-on-one-map

Comment: @JordiKroon any idea?